# Query performance with integer field larger than value, partitioned by another column

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, index

Our postgres 9 **Events** table contains 1 Million records, comprising of 2 fields: **Job** and **Task** (job is varchar; task is integer)

A single **Job** might have multiple sequential **Task**(s), for example:

| Job | Task |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| B | 1 |
| C | 1 |
| C | 2 |
| C | 3 |

We would like to pull all the records where the job's **task** is above a certain number, as follows:

```
select * from events where job='C' and task > 1 order by task desc
```

There might be up to thousands of records returned from the query.

What would be a proper index for the Events table, to optimize the query? or otherwise, what would be a good optimization for the query.

Edit by request from  @Vérace, here's the DDL to create the table:

```
create table events ( 
    id serial constraint task_events_pk primary key, 
    job varchar, 
    task integer
);
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! What is the Primary Key of your table? Please provide full DDL!

Comment: Do you really need `SELECT *` or can you `SELECT Only, TheColumns, YouActually, Need`? `SELECT *` is an anti-pattern and *can* hurt performance.

Comment: create table events
(
    id   serial constraint task_events_pk primary key,
    job  varchar,
    task integer
);

@Vérace-СлаваУкраїні

Comment: Please put any additional information into the question itself - scanning down through comments is cognitively dissonant. You can inform the person who asked for that extra info by notifying them using a comment with @ and their name like you have here. Could a `CONSTRAINT` be added to the table UNIQUE(job, task)? If so, then maybe you'd be better getting rid of the serial constraint altogether?

Comment: @Vérace-СлаваУкраїні - The question is about the optimization of the index in a query on 2 columns: On one hand, we have HASH index, which is great for "equals" criteria, and on the other hand - we have "BTree" index - which is great for the "larger then" query. But in the case above, notice that there is need to use those indices consecutively: the "Job='C'" part is best to pull out a chunk of the data, and the "task > 1" is best to use an ordered data structure of some sort - to prevent full scan of the previous results. What would be the postgres query behavior? and how can it be optimized?

Answer (score 0):

For this query to perform efficiently, the index needs the following

- All equality columns: `job`
- Then an inequality column: `task`
- Then all other columns: `id`

Since you also want it ordered by `task desc` you can sort the index that way also.

So you need `(job, task desc, id)`

Comment: Thank you @Charlieface. Do you know which index would be created? Do you know if the DB leverages consecutive indices? for example: searching 'job' with HASH index, and then searching 'task' with BTree index - for that subset of results? or is it that the only index used would be the HASH for the 'job' - and then there will be a full scan of the subset of results?

Comment: Not fully up to speed with Postgres, but I think it would create a B-Tree index by default. No use a single multi-column index, no other index should be necessary. A Hash index would not be good, because it can't do inequality and can't support an `ORDER BY`